# "npm install" stuck and error at "reify:date-fns" installation line

Tags: node.js, npm

So my project just get stuck at this line when i run "npm install" for some minutes, and after that it throw some huge error i can't just paste it here because it's too big.

But the start of the error is:

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/joao/Desktop/camaleao/camaleao-web-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/joao/Desktop/camaleao/camaleao-web-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entrando no diretório '/home/joao/Desktop/camaleao/camaleao-web-frontend/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIB
```

End of the error:

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/joao/Desktop/camaleao/camaleao-web-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-44-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/joao/Desktop/camaleao/camaleao-web-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/joao/Desktop/camaleao/camaleao-web-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Already deleted package-lock.json and node-modules.

❯ node -v
v16.13.1

❯ npm -v
8.3.0

Comment: how did you solve it ?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukKurt I can't remember exactly, but it was caused by some incompatibility with node/npm version and my sass package version, as you can see in the line 3 a error in node-sass path was occurring and throwing many others in cascade. I looked in sass version documentation and set my node/npm to the right versions and after that o ran `npm i` (just `i`).