# I am getting stuck in npm install

Tags: npm, node-modules, gatsby

everyone.
I am going to build and run gatsby project.
When I run the following command I get stuck and freezes.

```
npm install
...
reify:date-fns: timing reifyNode:node_modules/@parcel/transformer-js Completed in 17620ms
```

Could anyone tell me why this happens?
Thanks

I tried to uninstall npm, gatsby and reinstall, but it is same.

Comment: Does this help? Looks like it was a Node/NPM version issue, can you check if the projects `package.json` has an engine property with `node` defined? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70607905/npm-install-stuck-and-error-at-reifydate-fns-installation-line